# tesseract gem won't compile in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos, tesseract

Total noob here, but can't figure out how to get past this error. I'm hoping to install and run the 'tesseract' gem on my Linux server running Centos 6. The upshot seems to be that  -ltesseract should be in /usr/bin/ld, but isn't ...

I've read through the other tesseract / Ruby issues posted, but I don't think I have any of those problems.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Error message**

```
g++ -shared -fPIC    -o /tmp/.ffi-inline-0/3751549a49315e9a7703c6e20a39e587297ce8a8.so /tmp/.ffi-inline-0/3751549a49315e9a7703c6e20a39e587297ce8a8.cpp -ltesseract 2>>/tmp/.ffi-inline-0/3751549a49315e9a7703c6e20a39e587297ce8a8.log
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltesseract
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Error in action**

```
[x@y ~]# irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'tesseract'
CompilationError: compile error: see logs at /tmp/.ffi-inline-0/3751549a49315e9a7703c6e20a39e587297ce8a8.log
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:31:in `compile'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/builders/c.rb:114:in `shared_object'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:in `block in build'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `build'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in `singleton_inline'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.2/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:in `inline'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:34:in `<module:C>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:31:in `<module:Tesseract>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'1.9.3-p327
```

**Gem version**

```
[x@y ~]# gem list
[...]
tesseract-ocr (0.1.5)
[...]
```

**GCC version**

```
[x@y ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
[...]
```

**OS**

```
[x@y ~]# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
```

**Ruby version**

```
[x@y ~]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
```

**RVM Version** (just in case it matters)

```
[x@y ~]# rvm -v
rvm 1.17.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a tesseract package in your system.
I assume so `yum install tesseract`

Comment: `$ sudo yum install tesseract Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * epel: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
 * extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
 * updates: mirrors.vooservers.com
Setting up Install Process
No package tesseract available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Download an rpm package from
[link](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21766020/dir/centos_6/com/tesseract-3.02.02-3.1.i686.rpm.html)

Comment: Then install it with _yum –nogpgcheck install tesseract-3.02.02-3.1.i686.rpm_ (cd to _dir-with-package_)

P.S: you should always check packages from untrusted sources

Comment: You may also want to add repository RPMforge [link](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01)
And then install a package like regular one.
_yum install tesseract tesseract-en_
I think it's easiest way.

Comment: Sorry to continue to be a total noob here, but ... a) your first two comments say: download this thing, but don't ever trust things like I'm telling you to download (right?). So, I haven't downloaded it, per your advice. :/ b) So instead I followed the instructions in your third comment, but no dice: "No package tesseract available. No package tesseract-en available."

Comment: @Sam What if the same error persists in Mac. Is there any way to resolve it on mac

Comment: Sorry, @MaheshMesta I've been away from this for too long.